# Text editing web app

Tags: javascript, html5

```
try {
  var isSupported = !! new Blob();
} catch (e) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Sorry your browser isn\'t supported :(</h1>";
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
  inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file"),
  appname = "notepad",
  untitled = "untitled.txt",
  isModified = false,
  filename;

window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("txt")) { // Load localStorage
    newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name"));
  } else {
    newNote();
  }
};

window.onunload = function() {
  if (isModified) { // Save localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("txt", textarea.value);
    localStorage.setItem("name", filename);
  } else {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
};

textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  isModified = true;
});

function changeDocTitle(newFilename) { // Change doc title
  filename = newFilename;
  document.title = filename + " - " + appname;
}

function dontSave() { // Confirm dont save
  if (confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.")) {
    isModified = false;
    return true;
  }
}

function newNote(txt, name) { // New
  if (!isModified || dontSave()) {
    textarea.value = txt || "";
    changeDocTitle(name || untitled);
    if (textarea.value) {
      isModified = true;
    }
  }
  textarea.focus();
}

function openNote() { // Open
  if (!isModified || dontSave()) {
    inputFile.click();
  }
  textarea.focus();
}
inputFile.addEventListener("change", function() { // Load file
  var file = inputFile.files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    newNote(reader.result, file.name);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});

function rename() { // Rename
  var newFilename = prompt("Name this note:", filename);
  if (newFilename !== null) {
    if (newFilename === "") {
      changeDocTitle(untitled);
    } else {
      changeDocTitle(newFilename.lastIndexOf(".txt") == -1 ? newFilename + ".txt" : newFilename);
    }
    return true;
  }
}

function saveNote() { // Save
  if (rename()) {
    var blob = new Blob([textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n")], {
      type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, filename);
    isModified = false;
  }
  textarea.focus();
}

function getStats() { // Stats
  var txt = textarea.value,
    txtStats = {};
  txtStats.chars = txt.length;
  txtStats.words = txt.split(/\S+/g).length - 1;
  txtStats.lines = txt.replace(/[^\n]/g, "").length + 1;
  return txtStats.lines + " lines, " + txtStats.words + " words, " + txtStats.chars + " chars";
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { // Shortcuts
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && key == 78) { // Alt+Shift+N
    e.preventDefault();
    newNote();
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey) { // Ctrl+
    switch (key) {
      case 79: // O
        e.preventDefault();
        openNote();
        break;
      case 83: // S
        e.preventDefault();
        saveNote();
        break;
      case 75: // K
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(getStats());
        break;
      case 191: // /
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Help note for " + appname + " will be added soon!");
        break;
    }
  }
  if (key == 9) { // Tab
    e.preventDefault();
    var sStart = textarea.selectionStart,
      txt = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = txt.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + txt.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
    textarea.selectionEnd = sStart + 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- You do not need the `\` in `"<h1>Sorry your browser isn\'t supported :(</h1>"` because your string is surrounded with double quotes
- I would check immediately whether `textarea` and `inputFile` found something and give a proper error message when those elements are missing in the HTML
- You are doing both proper event handling with `textarea.addEventListener` and old skool event handling with `window.onload`, stick to proper event handling
- `"txt"` and `"name"` are the keys to interact with localStorage, these should be named constants
- Personally, I would try also to store the cursor position when storing the text in localStorage, this would look nice
- `dontSave() { // Confirm dont save` -> perhaps the function should be named differently ;)
- `saveAs` is missing ?

All in all a promising start for a cool editor. It helped me to build a jsbin for this : http://jsbin.com/jetuh/1/edit